# HTML5 Link to section

Tags: html

Well, in HTML 4.01 with for example `<div id="example">` I could make `<a href="#example">` to scroll to that div.

How can I make the same effect with `<section class="asd xyz">`?

Comment: Your question are extreme unreadable. I suggest you to post more details. But if you think 1 line it's enought description I think `Google` or `Bing` can help you.

Comment: Not a bad question. Most tutorials show the `<a name="codeword">` / `<a href="#codeword">` approach and `name` is already obsolete for HTML5.

Answer (score 23):

They work the same. Add an ID to the section and the link should work.

```
<section id="example"></section>
```

This code jumps to the section `#example`.

```
<a href="#example">Jump to example</a>
```

**EDIT:**
Pure HTML does not allow you to jump to class names and for a good reason. IDs are unique while classes can be reused as often as you want. Therefore you just can't jump to a class name since it probably doesn't have a single target.

Comment: What about linking to classes? I guess it's impossible?

Comment: Good answer, upvoted. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_section.asp) is a reading for `<section>` tags for added reference.